# Concat CLOB in PL/SQL for execute immediate

Tags: sql, database, oracle, plsql

I need to change a functions signature to have a parameter (p_param) of type CLOB, the previous type was nvarchar2.  This caused me trouble when existing code was using || to concat.

Here is the existing snippet, that worked just fine for the NVarchar2, but apparently when you use || to concat a CLOB it treats it like a nvarchar2, which is a problem when the character limit of nvarchar2 is exceeded.

```
 execute immediate    
    'select p.person_id 
     from person p where p.id in (' || p_param || ')'
 bulk collect into persons;
```

I tried to change the above snippet to be

```
  execute immediate   
   concat(concat('select p.id from person p where p.person_id in(',p_param),')')
  bulk collect into members;
```

This doesn't compile, I get an error,

> PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type

I am new to PL/SQL, thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you building a list of persons so long that it won't fit in a VARCHAR2 or NVARCHAR2 variable? I don't think Oracle likes to have SQLs that long. I would question the approach entirely.

Comment: Yes, I agree with you entirely.  I am maintaining some code, and would like to avoid rewriting the entire thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you have to modify this particular snippet of code to use DBMS_SQL, I would strongly consider changing it to eliminate the dynamic SQL approach entirely.  Instead, I would take Tom's [str2tbl](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061) function, modify it to take a CLOB (a subsequent reply has [already done this](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:110612348061#50831835557537)) and then change the code to

```
select p.person_id 
  bulk collect into persons
  from person p 
 where p.id in (select column_value
                  from str2tbl( p_param ))
```

At a minimum, that will let you avoid creating large numbers of non-sharable statements, reduce the number of hard parses and the amount of time spent parsing, and reduce the pressure on the shared pool.  It may also reduce the risk of things like SQL injection attacks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a CLOB for EXECUTE IMMEDIATE until 11g. Until then, you'll need to switch to DBMS_SQL.

http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:7032414607769#2445120800346017454